# How to deal with nested queries with a restclient in c#

Tags: c#, rest, request

I have the following code already to post a request:

```
string requestString = "https://api.bimobject.com/search/v1/products?Bearer_token=" + AccesToken + "&filter.brand.id="+BrandID;
var client = new RestClient(requestString);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");


IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Now I would like to add in an authentication token, which takes the following format according to the documentation:

```
     "auth": {
        "bearer": [
           {
              "key": "token",
              "value": "374bfdca122189f8c98e41ccd7a30212",
              "type": "string"
           }
        ],
        "type": "bearer"
     },
```

Now I'm not certain how to actually do this, it appears to be a nested parameter but I don't actually have any idea how to add in a nested parameter like that. I have already seen that

```
request.AddParameter("auth:bearer:[key:token,value:374bfdca122189f8c98e41ccd7a30212,type:string])
```

So how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Show the documentation you refer to in the question. adding a `Authorization: Bearer token` header should be enough to auth the request, which would look like `request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 374bfdca122189f8c98e41ccd7a30212");` for the rest client request based on the sample provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the sample token in the example, and assuming that value is stored in the `AccessToken` variable,

All you need to do is add the `Authorization` header to the request.

```
string requestString = "https://api.bimobject.com/search/v1/products?filter.brand.id=" + BrandID;
var client = new RestClient(requestString);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
//Assuming AccessToken = 374bfdca122189f8c98e41ccd7a30212 value in sample JSON
request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {AccessToken}");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

If reusing the client, an additional option would be to create an `IAuthenticator` derived class

```
public class BearerAuthenticator : IAuthenticator {
    private readonly string authHeader;

    public BearerAuthenticator(string accessToken) {
        if (accessToken == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("accessToken");

        authHeader = $"Bearer {accessToken}";
    }

    public void Authenticate(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request) {
        // only add the Authorization parameter if it hasn't been added by a previous Execute
        if (!request.Parameters.Any(p => p.Type.Equals(ParameterType.HttpHeader) &&
                                         p.Name.Equals("Authorization", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            request.AddParameter("Authorization", authHeader, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
    }
}
```

And assign it to the client

```
string requestString = "https://api.bimobject.com/search/v1/products?filter.brand.id=" + BrandID;
var client = new RestClient(requestString);
client.Authenticator = new BearerAuthenticator(AccessToken);

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Now, the `Authorization` header will be added to all requests made by that client, (provided the request does not have that header already set)

Comment: Thanks, that works(bounty to be awarded in 12 hours)!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have to pass the token through the HTTP headers like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer your-token
```

---

Any more context on what you're trying to accomplish would be nice, like some links to documentation if the service you're querying is free or if the POST requests needs the token in the request's body

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation just shows the code I gave and the comment to use the token provided (with the code I showed). I heard you can paste it into postman and it should work but I would like for it to work in c#. Anyway how would I pass it through the HTTP header?

Comment: As per how your code is structured in what you're showing something like this I think it should suffice:

```request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer your-token-here");```